# SQL MS Access just show 2 Data with same ID

Tags: sql, ms-access

my problem is just to show two rows of Data with same ID.

My Table looks like this:

```
------------------------------
- FlatDestID - Trefferspalte -
- 444555666  -       K       -
- 444555666  -       1       -
- 444555666  -       1       -
- 111222333  -       K       -
- 111222333  -       1       -
- 111222333  -       1       -
------------------------------
```

And i want to have my Table like this

```
------------------------------
- FlatDestID - Trefferspalte -
- 444555666  -       K       -
- 444555666  -       1       -
- 111222333  -       K       -
- 111222333  -       1       -
------------------------------
```

Sometimes i have the same ID four to five times. And i just want to show the first two Data for each FlatDestId like in the second example. That means if you have 5 times the same FlatDestId then just show the FlatDestId with "Trefferspalte = K" and then a secon Data with the same FlatDestId and "Trefferspalte = 1"

I hope you can understand my Question and the problem i need Solution for.

Greatings from Germany

---------- EDIT ----------

I have for "Trefferspalte" the Values K and 1-6 and i want to see always K and then another FlatDestId with 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6!

The Solution DISTINCT show's FlatDestId and Trefferspalte with all the Values that Exist for the FlatDestId and not K and just any Trefferspalte. I need to have two Values.

Comment: The absence of a PRIMARY KEY is an accident waiting to happen.

Comment: First edit your question and tag it properly. It is ms-access or mysql but not both. Then, how do you define "first two" ? Is that pure random or is there a specific order to keep ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access doesnt like much nested SQL queries, so first create a Query with this SQL :

```
SELECT K.FlatDestID, T.AnyTrefferspalte
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT FlatDestID 
    FROM <yourTable>
    WHERE Trefferspalte = 'K'
) K 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT FlatDestID, MIN(Trefferspalte) AS AnyTrefferspalte
    FROM <yourTable>
    WHERE Trefferspalte <> 'K'
    GROUP BY FlatDestID
) T
ON K.FlatDestID = T.FlatDestID
```

The goal is to know which are the *FlatDestID* that have **both** a 'K' *Trefferspalte* row **and** any other row. If there are multiple non-K *Trefferspalte*, here with `MIN(Trefferspalte)`, I have chosen to keep their minimum value. You can change it to `MAX()` to keep the higher value, or to `FIRST()` to keep the first one encountered, which in fact means **random**.

Name your query like you want, I have chosen *TempQuery*

Then, this query should give you the expected results:

```
SELECT FlatDestID, 'K' AS Trefferspalte FROM TempQuery
UNION ALL
SELECT FlatDestID, AnyTrefferspalte AS Trefferspalte FROM TempQuery
ORDER BY FlatDestID
```

On a side note: your table structure is weird and needs a serious redesign that would avoid you a lot of headaches. A Primary Key would be a good start.

Comment: Couldn't you just change the first query into `UNION ALL` instead of a JOIN? It would also cover cases where there aren't rows for both.

Comment: Yes Andre that will work too. Not sure if there would be any performance gain at all

Answer (score 0):

Make use of DISTINCT to remove duplicates, this will show your 2 rows. When you have more than 2 different values for Trefferspalte you will have to use some other method.

```
SELECT DISTINCT FlastDestID, Trefferspalte
FROM <yourTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to make both columns your primary keys so that it'll thrown an error if you receive duplicate values (so you won't save it in the table). If that's the existing setup and you can't do anything about it, try DISTINCT. If it won't work, then try grouping it (you just need to add a new column in your query:

```
SELECT FlatDestID, Trefferspalte, COUNT(*) FROM YourTable GROUP BY FlatDestID, Trefferspalte
```